# What are the different ways to center the button

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Random Color</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Welcome!</h1>

    <button>Click Me</button>

    <script src="app.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

i am new to web development

i am unable to center the button
how can i centre the button using css

Comment: by default is button an inline-element. As such it can be simply aligned with text-align.

Comment: @AmirNaeem different case. The linked duplicate is about cenetring a `div` within another `div`. By default a `div` is a block-level-element which spans the entire available width. This causes a complete different issue and solution then a button which is n inline-element with a width to fit-content

Comment: @tacoshy there is also a ton of duplicates about buttons as well

Answer (score 0):

The `<button>` by default is an inline-element. As such it can be aligned by using the `text-align`-property on the parent.

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Test Button</button>
</div>
```

Alternativly you can self-align the button by switching ot to a block-level-element by declaring `button { display: block; }` and center it with `margin: 0 auto;`

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<button>Test Button</button>
```

Last but not least you could use `Flexbox` or `CSS-Grid` however this also requires to declare it on the parent element while you could use `text-align` in the first place.